No data from Firestore displayed in the recycler view
I started with Firestore and I created a collection MealsDev containing one element.

I cannot display it in a recycler view. May you help with it?
In the meantime I have already checked other posts, but I didn't find what I'm doing wrong.
The permission on Firebase is set to
allow read, write: if true;

MealsFragment.java:
public class MealsFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentMealsBinding binding;
String collectionPath= "MealsDev";
DummyRecyclerAdapter dummyRecyclerAdapter;
RecyclerView dummyRecyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentMealsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();
    dummyRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.meals_recycler_view);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = db.collection(collectionPath).limit(10);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DummyMeal> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<DummyMeal>()
            .setQuery(query, DummyMeal.class)
            .build();

    dummyRecyclerAdapter = new DummyRecyclerAdapter(options);
    dummyRecyclerView.setAdapter(dummyRecyclerAdapter);
   
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    binding = null;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    dummyRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    dummyRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
}

}
DummyMeal.java
public class DummyMeal {
    String name;

    public DummyMeal() {
    }

    public DummyMeal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

DummyRecyclerAdapter.java
public class DummyRecyclerAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<DummyMeal, DummyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerDummyViewHolder> {
public DummyRecyclerAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<DummyMeal> options){
    super(options);
}

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DummyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerDummyViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull DummyMeal model) {
        String name = model.getName();
        holder.name.setText(name);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DummyRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerDummyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row_current_meal, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerDummyViewHolder(view);
    }

    public class RecyclerDummyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

        public RecyclerDummyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_meal_name);
        }


    }
}

recycler_view_row_current_meal.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_current_meal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_meal_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_meal_added_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_day_of_week"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                
                                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_meal_week"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

fragment_meals.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_meals_layout"
   >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="To jest test"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/meals_recycler_view"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>

UPDATE:
My aim is to display (in this case) a single record in the recycler view.
The debugger doesn't break if I set breakpoints in onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder.
I debugged the service once again setting a breakpoint in MealsFragment after a FirestoreRecyclerOptions in initialized.
It seems that the mSnapshot size is equal to 0. It should be 1 as far as I understand it. Maybe this is the problem? Why?

UPDATE 2:
I run the application on a mobile using Android 11 RP1A.
In the logs I can see a warning and an error related to GMS. I don't know if this is related.
I'm almost sure the data is not displayed due to a problem with a query.
Here are the entries from the log:
Failed to register com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller#com.google.android.gms
 dswf: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}

and then the error:
Failed to get service from broker. 
java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2376)
(...)


Please edit your code down to a [mre] and include specific details about your problem. What do you mean by "I cannot display it in a recycler view"? What did you expect to show and what result are you getting instead?

The code looks correct (and matching the data) at first glance, so you'll want to debug it locally. For example, if you put a breakpoint in onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder and run in the debugger, does it ever reach those breakpoints?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

@FrankvanPuffelen I update the description. Please take a look if you can

If onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder never get called, the adapter is not receiving any data from the database. I don't see why that happens though, so hopefully @AlexMamo has an idea on that.

I updated my question with some details from the log. Maybe it will be useful to look into this case

@alex-mamo Do you have an idea why the data isn't fetched from the Firestore db? I know it is asynch request, but in fact the data is never displayed in the recycler view.

You might be missing a LayoutManager on the RecyclerView. Without this, the RecyclerView won't know how to arrange its child views, leading to no data being displayed.
dummyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

Here’s a full guide from @Alex Mamo post on how to display data from Firestore into a RecyclerView using Android.
I hope this information helps to resolve your issue.

It works now, thanks
